# how do i fix Expected primary expression error

Tags: truffle, truffle-compile

Expected primary expression.
            j* = 10;
               ^
[image]

$ truffle migrate
Error parsing C:\Users\Welcome\Downloads\ethereum-dapp\contracts\Integers.sol: ParsedContract.sol:29:16: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
            j* = 10;
               ^
Compilation failed. See above.

Comment: function parseInt(string _value) 
        public
        returns (uint _ret) {
        bytes memory _bytesValue = bytes(_value);
        uint j = 1;
        for(uint i = _bytesValue.length-1; i >= 0 && i < _bytesValue.length; i--) {
            assert(_bytesValue[i] >= 48 && _bytesValue[i] <= 57);
            _ret += (uint(_bytesValue[i]) - 48)*j;
             j* = 10;
                
this is my contract

Comment: Can you edit and put the code in the main question? With formatting.

Comment: Would this be better `j *= 10;`?

Answer (score 1):

You've given space between '*' and '=' in `j* = 10;` , it's like this:

```
    j *= 10;
```

Good Luck!